# JQuery dialog button won't hide now I have converted my view to a telerik grid

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, telerik-grid

I have a link on my view that opens a JQuery dialog asking the user to confirm the action, on the ok button being clicked the dialog changes to a message either success or fail.

This works as expected and the action performed also works. However, once the ok button has been clicked that button should be hidden from view and since converting the standard mvc list view into a Telerik grid control the hiding of the button no longer functions but everything else still works as described.

I don't know how to pose the question in google to bring up the required responce as all answers point to completely different issue, I have also asked some of the senior developers in my team and no one has come across this before.

Can someone tell me what has happened to the JQuery  and how to counteract it please? help would be very much appreciated.

Razor view:

```
@model IEnumerable<BUUK.BSS.Models.ADTeamMemberEntry>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyTeam";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>




@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("TeamMember").Columns(c =>
{
    c.Bound(tm => tm.FullName);
    c.Bound(tm => tm.JobTitle);
    c.Bound(tm => tm.Department);
    c.Bound(tm => tm.Email);
    c.Template(
        @<text>
            @Html.ActionLink("User Details", "UserDetails", "User", new { userName = item.UserName }, null)
        </text>
        );
    })
)




<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create Review", "CreateReview", "Home", new { @class = "createReview" })</p>


<div style="display:none">
    @Html.Partial("CreateReview")

</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/confirmDialog.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/createReview.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.11.1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
}
```

JQuery Dialog:

```
$(function () {
    $(".createReview").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $("#create-review .CreateReviewSuccessMessage").hide();
        $("#create-review .CreateReviewFailureMessage").hide();

        $("#create-review").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            width: 425,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {

                    /*GET*/
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "GET",
                        async: true,
                        processData: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#create-review .CreateReviewConfirmDialog").hide();
                            $("#create-review .CreateReviewSuccessMessage").show();
                            $('.ui-button:contains("OK")').hide();
                            $('.ui-button:contains("Cancel")').find('span').text("Close");

                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            $("#create-review .CreateReviewConfirmDialog").hide();
                            $("#add-user-role .CreateReviewFailureMessage").show();
                            $('.ui-button:contains("OK")').hide();
                            $('.ui-button:contains("Cancel")').find('span').text("Close");
                        }
                    });
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $("#create-review .CreateReviewConfirmDialog").show();
                    $("#create-review .CreateReviewSuccessMessage").hide();
                    $("#create-review .CreateReviewFailureMessage").hide();
                }
            }
        });
        $("#create-review").dialog("open"); // <------- open dialog this way.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some code. you should check the source code to see what the button name is and where is is held.

Try: `$('.ui-dialog-buttonset button:contains("OK")').hide();`